# Sharing Facebook Link via Javascript SDK returns Error 500

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a Facebook sharer.
It needs to be able to share both **regular links** (e.g. http://google.com) and **Facebook content** (e.g. http://facebook.com/10152718496295746).

In order to do this I invoke the JS APIs as follow:

`FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: #LINK#,
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});`

But while this works just fine with regular links, it returns an error 500 on Facebook contents.

**EDIT**

It turns out that Facebook crawler won't scrape Facebook links and thus they can't be shared this way. Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Facebook Crawler return 500 when attempting to crawl its own links. So you won't be able to do as described in the answer.

But you can always create a popup window pointing to the Facebook sharer.php in order to share that Facebook Post.